# differece between for loops in Java and foreach loop in PHP

Tags: java, php

In PHP we use....

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

In Java the same thing can be done using

```
for (int e : array) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

is there any difference between the above 2 code segments

Answer (score 2):

This is very close to what both forms of java for-each iterator (numeric and Iterator) do, but PHP iterator also can provide keys and bind the iterated value by-reference, so you could modify it in place if you wanted to.

Comment: +1 for modify in place. That seems to be the main difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Java but your example suggests you need specify a data type for the index. PHP is loosely typed so you can use a foreach loop on associative and mixed arrays, not only pure numeric arrays. But, it's also possible to foreach your own custom *objects* just by implementing the [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).